# Memory leak in .NET Core 3.0 app when using NLog or Serilog

Tags: c#, .net-core, .net-core-3.0

I am having a strange issue with .NET Core 3.0 while using loggers.

The app works ok on Windows, but when I start it on Linux (Debian 10) as a daemon, it just keeps taking more and more memory. 
The issue was first manifested when I was using NLog, then I switched to Serilog, but the issue is still here. The problem is not there when I remove NLog/Serilog.

Using memory snapshots and Jetbrains dotMemory all I get is a bunch of sbyte arrays that are created (probably) by NLog/Serilog.

When I disable logging to a file and leave just console logging - the problem disappears!

I tried adding manual calls to Garbage collector but that didn't help.

We managed to create a workaround by adding MemoryMax parameter in ther .service file. It seems that garbage collector starts cleaning up when it is near the Max limit. (ie the limit is 150 MB and now the app is holding at 145 MB).

Does anyone have any idea what might be wrong? Or should I just address this issue with NLog and Serilog developers.

Comment: is this 'memory leak' increasing in size or does it stop at some point? did you check the settings of the logigng providers - they must allocate some buffers somewhere and you should be able to maybe limit this. It is weird that it differs when running on linux however.

Comment: you have issue when NLog or Serilog logger is working on Linux. But why do you think that the problem is in particular logger library? It is strange that two different logging libraries shows the same problem. Have you tried any other logger that works fine?

Comment: @sommmen The service starts with aprox 35 MB and over the weekend it grew to 700MB. So I guess it stops only when the OS kills it. As I said, it does however stop, or rather GC cleans up, if I add MemoryMax parameter for the daemon. But this is a workaround that is threading "dangerous ground". 
I will try to see if logging providers have any buffer limits - even though we tried setting it up to flush the buffers more often, but it didn't help.

Comment: @oleksa It IS very strange! I haven't tried any other loggers. And these ones have problems only when logging to a file and on Linux.
And I know the problems is with the loggers or rather when using them, because if I remove logging to a file - the problem disappears.

Comment: I mean that (probably) you are using the logger in some unusual way. Or (just guessing) there is a bug in the asp.net container on Linux.

Comment: @oleksa If you would belive, I am using it in a basic way with no special requirements, just logging on screen and in a rolling file. 
My suspicion is the garbage collector because it cleans up when it reaches the MemoryMax limit...
I will try the suggestions sarin posted bellow.

Answer (score 5):

I have also noticed high memory consumption. There have been a few different things to try including:

- using .Destructure.ToMaximumCollectionCount(10) // Default is int.MaxValue
- removing .Enrich.WithExceptionDetails to see if the memory issue magically disappears
- Checking the Swap file memory usage of the Linux container and hence setting the Swapiness value (although take care of unintended consequences)

To be certain about where the memory leak is happening though you will need to analyse the memory heap to look at what objects are using up the memory.

[SeriLog Memory Leak using EF](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1275)

Comment: I will try the first point with .Destructure. I am not using Enrich.WithExceptionDetails so that is not the cause. 
And it is not running in a container - it is in a clean Debian distro.
I will post the results when I try.

Comment: After extensive testing, I am sad to report that it didn't work. Everything points to garbage collector not doing its job properly. But I will report on my findings when I have them. Thank you for trying to help!

Comment: Sounds like something in your objects isn't being disposed of properly. Crack it open with a memory profiler.

Answer (score 1):

NLog opens/closes the file for each file-write operation by default. This ensures the highest level of compatibility but it has a cost.

Try configuring NLog like this:

```
<nlog>
   <targets>
      <target type="file" name="logfile" fileName="log.txt" keepFileOpen="true" concurrentWrites="false" />
   </targets>
   <rules>
      <logger name="*" minLevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
   </rules>
</nlog>
```

Do not use `<targets async="true">` if memory allocation is an issue.

NLog ver. 4.7 fixes a performance issue when using `concurrentWrites="true"` together with NLog archiving-options on non-Windows-platforms. Until NLog ver. 4.7 is released then one should consider configuring `concurrentWrites="false"` if possible.

See also: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/performance

Comment: You saved my day! Thanks you.